# Перегрузка операторов с++

Tags: c++

Скажите, как переписать операторы == и != ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да так же, как и другие.

```
bool operator ==(Type const & left, Type const & right)
{
    ...
    return ...;
}
bool operator !=(Type const & left, Type const & right)
{
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: не знал, что нужно указать как дружественную, а потом определять вне класса.

Comment: @doomsday: Можно в принципе и как member-функцию с одним аргументом. Но внешняя концептуально правильнее.

Comment: @VladD, аргументируйте, пожалуйста. Просто для расширения моего кругозора. Спасибо.

Comment: @BuilderC: member-функция несимметрична: в ней первый аргумент (`this`) выделен по сравнению со вторым. А операции обычно симметричны. Т. е. получается не очень красиво. Это раз.

Затем, если вы хотите определить оператор, в котором первый аргумент другого типа, который не под вашим контролем? Например, вы хотите, чтобы ваш строковой тип можно было складывать с числами: `5 + MyString("abc")`. Тогда member-функция не подойдёт (т. к. вы не можете дописать функцию к `int`), а внешняя функция покатит.

То есть внешняя функция работает всегда, а member — иногда, лишь если вам не хочется странного.